# Difference in y value when using url vs tileUrlFunction in VectorTileSource OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-6, vector-tiles

I'm using GeoServer MVT layers in OpenLayers and to add them to the map I just do:

```
const source = new VectorTileSource({
      url:`${geoserverUrl}/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf`,
      format: new MVT(),
      wrapX: true,
      tileGrid: createXYZ({ maxZoom: 19 })
    });

const layer = new VectorTileLayer({
    className: "myLayer",
    source: source,
    minResolution: 0,
    maxResolution: 2,
    style: myStyle(),
    visible: true
  });
```

So far so good. Now I would like to use the tileUrlFunction instead of defining the url attribute as I would like to define a different layer in the url based on the zoom level, and for that I used the following function that I called in the attribute tileUrlFunction of the `new VectorTileSource` instantiation:

```
    const tileUrlFunction = (tileCoord) => {
        if (tileCoord[0] > 18) {
          return `${geoserverUrl}/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:layer1@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/${tileCoord[0]}/${tileCoord[1]}/${tileCoord[2]}.pbf`;
        } else {
return `${geoserverUrl}/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:layer2@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/${tileCoord[0]}/${tileCoord[1]}/${tileCoord[2]}.pbf`;
         }   
      };
    };
```

The problem is that when using tileUrlFunction, on render, I get a wrong y value (corresponding to tileCoord[2]).
When using `${geoserverUrl}/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/myworkspace:mylayer@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf` I get for instance the coordinates /18/258309/**98012**.pbf and the tile renders correctly on the map, when I use the tileUrlFunction I get the wrong y 18/2258309/**164130**.pbf, and the tile fails to render.

I noticed that **if I don't** put the dash in the y when defining the url "...@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{**-y**}.pbf", I also get the same wrong value.

Reading the docs I can see that

> Grids like TMS where x 0 and y 0 are in the bottom left can be used by
> using the {-y} placeholder in the URL template, so long as the source
> does not have a custom tile grid

I'm quite sure this issue is related to the definition of the tileGrid, but I don't know how to make the function tileUrlFunction to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers will be passing the tile coordinates for an XYZ source.  To convert to TMS use

```
const z = tileCoord[0];
const x = tileCoord[1];
const y = Math.pow(2, z) - tileCoord[2] - 1;
```

Comment: I tried that but still didn't get the right value for y.

Comment: It works when I replace the `url` in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html with a `tileUrlFunction` https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-selection-forked-ujl8m

Comment: Actually what I did before was  (Math.pow(2, tileCoord[0] - 1) + tileCoord[2]) which didn't work. Your suggestion is the right answer!

Comment: For those who want to know more: https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720